# How to loop through each visible char of a TRichEdit text?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio, trichedit

In Delphi 10.3.3, which is the most simple and fastest and most efficient way to loop through each visible `Char` (i.e. excluding non-printable characters such as e.g. `#13`) of a (multiline) `TRichEdit` text? I then need to get and set the color of each char according to my calculations.

I have tried this one:

```
function GetCharByIndex(Index: Integer): Char;
begin
  RichEdit1.SelStart := Index;
  RichEdit1.SelLength := 1;
  Result := RichEdit1.SelText[1];
end;

RichLen := RichEdit1.GetTextLen - RichEdit1.Lines.Count;
for i := 0 to RichLen - 1 do
begin
  c := GetCharByIndex(i);
  if c = #13 then CONTINUE;
  // ... do my stuff here
end;
```

But I am sure there must be a better way.

Comment: Related: [Faster Rich Edit Syntax Highlighting](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol3/9910/Faster_rich_edit_syntax_highlighting.htm). It is written for C++Builder but everything it says applies to Delphi, too

Comment: How did the text get into the edit box in the first place?  What about formatting it while it is being input rather than afterwards - you should have more information at that point to be able to do it more intelligently.  Hard to say more without understanding the larger problem...

Comment: RichEdit is relatively slow in general. If you're after syntax highlighting kind of control, I would suggest for example SynEdit (or Scintilla for Delphi); those are for such purpose faster than RichEdit control.

Comment: @TLama I am creating something totally new: A way to show the differences between two texts using colors.

Comment: It's not a new application; we normally use such for comparing source code. Anyway, from my experience I'd not use RichEdit. Controls I've mentioned are (or at least were) relatively faster.

Comment: @user1580348 There are lots of optimized libraries for generating and viewing diffs.  Reinventing the wheel can be instructive, but when you can use something that already exists it's usually well worth your while.

Comment: @J... "There are lots of optimized libraries for generating and viewing diffs." - Could you name a few you consider the best?

Comment: @user1580348 No, because I've not had need of them.  You might find [this](https://cc.embarcadero.com/item/17118) useful, however.  Generally third-party component recommendations are off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var
  i: Integer;  
  c: Char;
  cord: Integer;
...
i := -1;
for c in RichEdit1.Text do
begin
  Inc(i);
  cord := ord(c);
  if (cord = 13) then
    Dec(i);
  if (cord >= 32) and (not ((cord > 126) and (cord < 161))) then
  begin
    // do your stuff here, for example exchanging red and green colors:
    RichEdit1.SelStart := i;
    RichEdit1.SelLength := 1;
    if RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color = clGreen then
      RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clRed
    else if RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color = clRed then
      RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clGreen;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That's very slow. For such a basic solution it was a pity to write a question

Comment: What is "slow"? On my computer, it's very fast. Measure it.

Comment: If that were enough, I would like to use this simplification years ago. But it's up to you. Both MS Word and Write.exe uses TOM. And also other text programs.

Comment: Measured it: 0.025 seconds for 228 chars.

Comment: For small tasks we can use small solutions. I agree.

Comment: @MiroslavBaláž Previously I had a rather complex solution. But then Manitou gave me this simpler solution. And I stuck with it.